# Selenium webdriver not able to select element.Getting "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with" error

Tags: java, api, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using selenium webdriver with eclipse,testng & firefox browser
I am trying to click a dropdown with id "compName" but I am not able to click it.
I have tried all possible scenarios to identify the drodpown but I always get this error "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with"
The html code for it is as follows

```
<div id="login" class="b-container" style="display:block">
<form action="" name="passwordForm" commandname="passwordForm" method="post">
<input id="userVo.email" type="hidden" name="userVo.email">
</form>
<form action="" name="resetForm" commandname="resetForm" method="post"> </form>
<form id="loginForm" class="form-login" onsubmit="return onClickLogin();" name="loginForm" action="" method="post">
<input id="compLocId" type="hidden" name="compLocId" value="1">
<h2 class="form-login-heading">SIGN IN NOW</h2>
<div class="login-wrap">
<div id="invDivMsg" style="color:red;"></div>
<input id="loginId" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="User ID" name="loginId" disabled="" vk_156ee="subscribed">
<input id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" disabled="" vk_156ee="subscribed">
<button id="signIn" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btn-drop marginLeft23" type="submit" style="width: 80%; display: none;" disabled="">Sign in</button>
<button id="reset" class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block btn-drop marginLeft23" onclick="onClickReset()" type="reset" style="width: 80%;">Reset</button>
<div class="select col-md-12">
<select id="compName" onchange="fillLocDrpDown();" name="compName" style="display: block;">
<option value="">Select Company</option>
<option value="5">XYZ ltd</option>
<option value="6">Freight Forwarder Co</option>
<option value="2">CHA</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: It might be encapsulated in container elements which handle the click. Try clicking one of those. The actual input element is hidden. The way I solve that is by just trying every one of them until I find the one I need. Go up from the first parent the input has.

Comment: So in this case, try clicking `<div class="select col-md-12">`. I think that is the one you need.\

Comment: code did you tried to help you ?

Comment: If required element is hidden by default, you can make it visible using `JavaScript`. In `Python` this should looks like `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('compName').style.visibility = 'visible';")`, but in `Java` similar method looks more complicated and I'm afraid I cannot help you with `Python` to `Java` code "translation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use explicit wait and expected conditions

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("compName")));
element.click();
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for the dropdown to be visible.

Comment: Thanks.Using the above code I am able to click the element.